# A country winning all 3 medals at a Summer Olympics event

Tags: trivia, olympics, awards

At the 2020 Tokyo Olympics, the Jamaican sprinters Elaine Thompson-Herah, Shelly-Ann Fraser-Pryce, and Shericka Jackson swept the 100 meters women's medals by winning gold, silver, and bronze respectively. Also earlier in the games, in women's cross-country cylcing, the Swiss athletes swept the medals.

However, in many competitions only 1 athlete per country is allowed per weight class, or no more than 2 in a discipline (swimming nowadays for example). So I'd think such a feat is uncommon.

How many times, all 3 medals of a single event was won by athletes of just one country in a summer Olympics event? Please limit your answer to 1948 games and forward as I suspect this feat was more common in the older days due to limited participations.

Comment: Swimming used to have 3 per country, changing after the Montreal games where there were sweeps.

Comment: I had heard swimming had a higher limit, hence the "nowadays". Do you know if the sweeps in swimming were common or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[There are some lists on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Podium_sweep) that show so called **Medal Sweeps** in athletics, speed and figure skating, snowboarding and cross-country skiing.

So from these lists alone you can see that this still seems to be quite common, especially as there are lots of different events not listed; for the athletics events alone this has happened 41 times since the 1948 games.

I have also found [a dataset](https://github.com/Sabriel567/cs373-idb/wiki/11.-Database-Setup) that includes all the medals awarded until the 2008 Olympic Summer Games in Peking. So I wrote a script that collected all the Medal Sweeps in Summer Games from 1948 until 2008 and got a total of 98 Medal Sweeps. When looking at [another data source](http://www.olympedia.org/lists/1/automatic) I could find another 7 results that happened after 2008, or have not been in the first dataset, bringing it to a total of **105 Medal Sweeps** since the 1948 Summer Games.

Keep in mind that i did not fact check all of these, or the datasets in general, but from what I could see it seems to be mostly correct.
Also there are results included where more than three medals have been awarded in total, with one NOC taking at least one gold, silver and bronze medal, as well as results where not all three different medals were awarded (for example because of a tie for second place where a second silver, but no bronze medal was given out) but a single NOC still took all three medals.

This is the full list of events and the corresponding NOC that achieved this:

| Year | Discipline | Event | Gender | NOC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1948 | Artistic Gymnastics | pommel horse | M | FIN |
| 1948 | Diving | 3m springboard | M | USA |
| 1948 | Diving | 3m springboard | W | USA |
| 1948 | Swimming | 200m breaststroke | M | USA |
| 1948 | Athletics | 110m hurdles | M | USA |
| 1948 | Athletics | 3000m steeplechase | M | SWE |
| 1948 | Athletics | shot put | M | USA |
| 1952 | Diving | 10m platform | W | USA |
| 1952 | Diving | 3m springboard | M | USA |
| 1952 | Athletics | 110m hurdles | M | USA |
| 1952 | Athletics | 200m | M | USA |
| 1952 | Athletics | decathlon | M | USA |
| 1952 | Athletics | discus throw | W | URS |
| 1952 | Athletics | shot put | M | USA |
| 1952 | Fencing | sabre individual | M | HUN |
| 1952 | Artistic Gymnastics | rings | M | URS |
| 1952 | Artistic Gymnastics | vault | W | URS |
| 1956 | Diving | 10m platform | W | USA |
| 1956 | Swimming | 100m butterfly | W | USA |
| 1956 | Swimming | 100m freestyle | M | AUS |
| 1956 | Swimming | 100m freestyle | W | AUS |
| 1956 | Athletics | 110m hurdles | M | USA |
| 1956 | Athletics | 200m | M | USA |
| 1956 | Athletics | 20km walk | M | URS |
| 1956 | Athletics | 400m hurdles | M | USA |
| 1956 | Athletics | discus throw | M | USA |
| 1956 | Fencing | épée individual | M | ITA |
| 1960 | Athletics | 110m hurdles | M | USA |
| 1960 | Athletics | 400m hurdles | M | USA |
| 1960 | Athletics | discus throw | M | USA |
| 1960 | Athletics | shot put | M | USA |
| 1960 | Artistic Gymnastics | floor exercises | W | URS |
| 1960 | Artistic Gymnastics | individual all-round | W | URS |
| 1960 | Artistic Gymnastics | uneven bars | W | URS |
| 1960 | Artistic Gymnastics | vault | W | URS |
| 1964 | Diving | 3m springboard | M | USA |
| 1964 | Swimming | 200m backstroke | M | USA |
| 1964 | Swimming | 400m freestyle | W | USA |
| 1964 | Swimming | 400m individual medley | W | USA |
| 1968 | Swimming | 100m butterfly | M | USA |
| 1968 | Swimming | 100m freestyle | W | USA |
| 1968 | Swimming | 200m freestyle | W | USA |
| 1968 | Swimming | 200m individual medley | M | USA |
| 1968 | Swimming | 200m individual medley | W | USA |
| 1968 | Athletics | 400m | M | USA |
| 1968 | Artistic Gymnastics | floor exercises | M | JPN |
| 1972 | Swimming | 200m butterfly | M | USA |
| 1972 | Swimming | 200m butterfly | W | USA |
| 1972 | Artistic Gymnastics | floor exercises | W | URS |
| 1972 | Artistic Gymnastics | horizontal bar | M | JPN |
| 1972 | Artistic Gymnastics | individual all-round | M | JPN |
| 1972 | Artistic Gymnastics | parallel bars | M | JPN |
| 1976 | Swimming | 100m butterfly | M | USA |
| 1976 | Swimming | 200m backstroke | M | USA |
| 1976 | Swimming | 200m breaststroke | W | URS |
| 1976 | Swimming | 200m butterfly | M | USA |
| 1976 | Swimming | 200m butterfly | W | GDR |
| 1976 | Swimming | 200m freestyle | M | USA |
| 1976 | Athletics | hammer throw | M | URS |
| 1976 | Athletics | pentathlon | W | GDR |
| 1976 | Fencing | sabre individual | M | URS |
| 1980 | Swimming | 100m backstroke | W | GDR |
| 1980 | Swimming | 100m butterfly | W | GDR |
| 1980 | Swimming | 100m freestyle | W | GDR |
| 1980 | Swimming | 200m backstroke | W | GDR |
| 1980 | Swimming | 200m breaststroke | W | URS |
| 1980 | Swimming | 200m freestyle | W | GDR |
| 1980 | Swimming | 400m freestyle | M | URS |
| 1980 | Swimming | 400m freestyle | W | GDR |
| 1980 | Athletics | 800m | W | URS |
| 1980 | Athletics | hammer throw | M | URS |
| 1980 | Athletics | pentathlon | W | URS |
| 1984 | Athletics | 200m | M | USA |
| 1988 | Archery | individual FITA round | W | KOR |
| 1988 | Athletics | 400m | M | USA |
| 1988 | Athletics | hammer throw | M | URS |
| 1988 | Athletics | long jump | M | USA |
| 1988 | Athletics | pole vault | M | URS |
| 1988 | Fencing | foil individual | W | FRG |
| 1988 | Artistic Gymnastics | individual all-round | M | URS |
| 1988 | Table Tennis | singles | W | CHN |
| 1992 | Athletics | 3000m steeplechase | M | KEN |
| 1992 | Athletics | hammer throw | M | EUN |
| 1992 | Athletics | long jump | M | USA |
| 1992 | Badminton | singles | M | INA |
| 1992 | Equestrian Dressage | individual | X | GER |
| 1992 | Artistic Gymnastics | individual all-round | M | EUN |
| 2000 | Archery | individual | W | KOR |
| 2000 | Badminton | doubles | W | CHN |
| 2004 | Athletics | 200m | M | USA |
| 2004 | Athletics | 3000m steeplechase | M | KEN |
| 2004 | Athletics | 400m | M | USA |
| 2004 | Athletics | long jump | W | RUS |
| 2008 | Athletics | 100m | W | JAM |
| 2008 | Athletics | 400m | M | USA |
| 2008 | Athletics | 400m hurdles | M | USA |
| 2008 | Fencing | sabre individual | W | USA |
| 2008 | Table Tennis | singles | M | CHN |
| 2008 | Table Tennis | singles | W | CHN |
| 2008 | Tennis | singles | W | RUS |
| 2012 | Athletics | 200m | M | JAM |
| 2012 | Fencing | foil individual | W | ITA |
| 2016 | Athletics | 100m hurdles | W | USA |
| 2020 | Athletics | 100m | W | JAM |
| 2020 | Cycling | cross-country | M | SUI |

Comment: Nice work digging that up!

Comment: I think this article may confuse the 3km steeplechase with the 5km.

Comment: @NeilMeyer as far as i can see there was only the 3km steeplechase at the 2004 and 1992 Olympic Games, am i missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

To add to the already good answer Kenya had a clean sweep in the men's 5km steeplechase in 2004 and 1992. Finland had a clean sweep in the event in 1928 and Sweden had one in 1948.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steeplechase_at_the_Olympics)